# Why is $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ always a constant?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

Today in class we learned that for exponential functions $f(x) = b^x$ and their derivatives $f'(x)$, the ratio is always constant for any $x$. For example for $f(x) = 2^x$ and its derivative $f'(x) = 2^x \cdot \ln 2$

$$\begin{array}{c | c | c | c}
x & f(x) & f'(x) & \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\\ \hline
-1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0.346  & 0.693 \\
0 & 1 & 0.693 & 0.693 \\
1 & 2 & 1.38 &  0.693\\
2 & 4 & 2.77 &0.693&
\end{array}$$

So as you can see, the ratio is the same and this is true for all functions of the form $b^x$ and its derivative. So my question is, why is the ratio always constant? Is there some proof or logic behind it or is *just like that*? Furthermore, what's the use of knowing this?

EDIT:

It seems that I have missed the fairly simple

$$\require{cancel}\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{\cancel{{b^x}}\ln\,b}{\cancel{{‌​b^x}}}=\ln\,b$$

But what's the use knowing and learning this? Will this reduce a step in the future or help solve a much harder problem more easily?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me if you're asking for a proof or for an intuitive reason why this happens. Also note that $\ln (2)=0.6931471806\ldots$

Comment: $$\require{cancel}\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{\cancel{{b^x}}\ln\,b}{\cancel{{b^x}}}=\ln\,b$$

Comment: Note that the left hand side could be read as $[\ln f(x)]'$, so that $[\ln a^x]' = [x \ln a]' = \ln a$ is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f=a^x$$
$$f'=\ln a \times a^x$$
So, $$f'=\ln a \times f$$
So, $$\dfrac{f'}{f}=\ln a= \text{constant}=0.693\Big|_{a=2}$$

Comment: What's the use of knowing this? Or in other words, why am I learning it? Is it going to make a future problem much easier to solve, what's its significance?

Comment: There's no significance, if you have function as yours. And you get to calculate single differentiation of $\dfrac{f'}{f}$, its just $0$, you don't need to think hard for this.

Comment: @gekko, for now, treat it as a nice property of the exponential function. Later, when you get to solving differential equations, this fact might prove useful...

Comment: Yes , DE of a exponential function is $f'=Kf$.

Comment: @gekkostate: It just tells you that every time you differentiate an exponential function, there is a factor of previous function.  Do you get it?

Comment: @Inceptio The only reason I'm thinking "hard" about this is because we spent about 75 mins learning this and I had no idea why and teacher didn't specify why this important or useful but I know why and I know it's significance - helps with differential equations.

Answer (score 2):

$f'/f$ is called the [Logarithmic Derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative) of $f$.

By the [Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)
$$
\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(f(x))
$$
Since $\log(b^x)=x\log(b)$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}x\log(b)=\log(b)$, we get that $f'/f$ is constant.